# Отследить долгое нажатие на кнопку (Key) в клавиатуре и изменить иконку

Tags: java, android

Делаю кастомную клавиатуру. Нажатии на кнопки я отслеживаю в переопределенном методе `onKey`:

```
@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(primaryCode);

    switch (primaryCode){
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            break;
        ........
    }
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при долгом нажатии на кнопку, например `caps`, изменилась иконка, а при одинарном нажатии изменилась на другое.

Искал везде, но нигде не говорится об отслеживании обычного долгого нажатия на кнопки. Везде говорится о `popup view`

**Вопросы:**

**1)** Как все таки отследить долгое нажатие определенной кнопки

**2)** Как менять иконки в методе `onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes)`, если `primaryCode` мне уже известен. Так как везде делают `For Each` и только потом меняют иконки, например:

```
Keyboard currentKeyboard = mInputView.getKeyboard();            
List<Keyboard.Key> keys = currentKeyboard.getKeys();
mInputView.invalidateKey(primaryCode);

for(int i = 0; i < keys.size() - 1; i++ )
{
    Keyboard.Key currentKey = keys.get(i);

    if(currentKey.codes[0] == primaryCode) 
    {
        currentKey.label = null;
        currentKey.icon = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email);
        break; 
    }
}
```

Может можно и без цикла обойтись, так как мне итак известна кнопка с этим `keyCode`?

Comment: а почему нет? они используют цикл для поиска нужно кнопки

Comment: В том то и дело, что мне уже известна кнопка или я что то упускаю?

Comment: так я и написал, что можно спокойно убрать цикл и сразу писать код для вашей кнопки.

Comment: Только вот как??) Не знаю куда вставить мой primaryCode

Comment: В том-то и дело, что "вставить" его некуда. Вам даётся список всех кнопок, и найти в нём нужную можно либо перепробовав все на соответствие заданному параметру, либо зная её позицию в списке.